# Swipe action on RWD Product Gallery

Tags: product-images, rwd-theme, gallery, elevate

Using RWD theme on mobile, is it possible to get product images to swipe to the next/prev image instead of clicking the thumbnail. I dont think elevatezoom has an option for this.